# Dynamically grow merged cell's height

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I want to display text in a cell whose length will vary. The cell should accommodate more than 5K characters. That is why I merged three adjacent cells and three rows.

The cell's height is not changing dynamically.

Sample code I have implemented:

```
Sub pqrs(ByVal target as Range)
    Dim r as Range
    Set a = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(B1:D3) 
    a.Value = "large text........."
    abcd.a '--- Called below Proc.
    a.Merge
End Sub

Sub abcd(ByVal target as Range)
    Dim r as Range
    Dim defaultHeight as Integer
    Dim maxtHeight as Integer
    Dim length as Integer
    Dim heightToUse as Double

    defaultHeight = 12
    maxHeight = 409
    taget.merge

    For Each r in target.Cells(1)
    length = Len(r.Value)
        If length >= 1000 and length <= 2000 Then
            heightToUse = defaultHeight + 100
            If (heightToUse > maxHeight) Then
                r.RowHeight = maxHeight
            Else
                r.RowHeight = heightToUse
            End If  
        ElseIf length > 2000 and length <= 4000 Then
            heightToUse = defaultHeight + 200
            If (heightToUse > maxHeight) Then
                r.RowHeight = maxHeight
            Else
                r.RowHeight = heightToUse
            End If  
        Else
            r.RowHeight = defaultHeight
        End If
        r.WrapText = True
    Next r
End Sub
```

Comment: Does this code even compile?

Comment: Use `Option Explicit` and you will quickly locate silly mistakes like `taget.mergge`.

Comment: Tough to find the problem without seeing the data and the page setup, but, my guess is that what you need to do is to wrap the text (e.g. `Selection.WrapText = True` )

Comment: @Jeeped: It's Typo. I have used merge in actual code.

Comment: @Tim: Yes. This Code getting compiled.

Comment: `Set a = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(B1:D3)` - this will not compile

Comment: Used, Set a = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B1:D3")

Comment: Better to post your *actual* code, instead of a version with typos

Comment: @Tim: I have edited my code.

Comment: Current posted code is working fine, if text height is not more than 436(409+12+12) pixels.

If text height is more than that, merged cells(B1:D3) height should increase.
In my code, Only first row height is getting increased.

So, I want my Code should behave like this,
If text height is more than 409 pixels, next row in merged cells i.e. second row height should increase as per the remaining text height.
If text height is more than 818 pixels, next row in merged cells i.e. third row height should increase as per the remaining text height.

Answer (score 0):

I see multiple problems in your code.

1) Not only is "merge" spelled as "mergge", as @Jeeped pointed out, "target" is spelled as "taget"

2) `Dim maxtHeight As Integer` should be `Dim maxHeight As Integer`

3) `For Each r In target` needs to be `For Each r in target.rows` or `For Each r in target.cells`, or something, I can't really tell without seeing your example.

4) You probably need to merge the text in order to get the results I think you want (e.g., `r.WrapText = True`).

When I corrected all your errors, the heights do change, but I can't be sure if it truly achieves your desired results, because I haven't seen your spreadsheet or the actual data. Please correct all these typos. If the code still doesn't work, please post a sample of your spreadsheet so we can see the actual layout and data.